# Парсинг вывода curl

Tags: json, curl, sed

запрос curl выводит длинную json строку.
`curl -H "Api-Key: d4447TEST8d3cf" "https://test_project.ru/issues.json"`

часть строки вывода выглядит примерно так:

`{ ... "done_posic":10,"test_field":[{"id":12,"name":"Customer Id","value":""},{"id":31,"name":"Customer Email","value":"test@mail.ru"},{"id":4,"name":"Customer Ip","value":""}],"created_on":"2016-09-26T11:30:06Z","updated_on":"2016-09-27T10:20:08Z"}],"total_count":26,"offset":0,"limit":25}`

Нужно вырезать `"total_count":26` либо даже просто его значение, только цифру.

Как можно распарсить этот текст? Пытался играться с sed, но т.к. значение нужного параметра может быть и 2-3-4 значным, то не очнь понятно как правильно сформировать маску.
Вхождение параметра total_count - всегда одно и находится в самом конце вывода строки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `jq`:

```
curl -H "Api-Key: d4447TEST8d3cf" "https://test_project.ru/issues.json" | jq '.total_count'
```

Answer (score 0):

например, так:

```
$ ... | sed -n 's/.*"total_count":\([[:digit:]]\+\),.*/\1/p'
26
```

подразумевается, что между `"total_count":` и `,` находится минимум одна десятичная цифра.

если вместо запятой может быть что-нибудь иное (но отличное от десятичной цифры), то запятую можно смело убрать из выражения.

Comment: Не получилось по вашему методу почему-то :) не выводит вообще ничего. Пробовал с запятой и без...синтаксис sed конечно адский ад....

Comment: на предоставленном вами образце данных — работает. вероятно, вы проверяете на данных, отличных от образца.